# why Copy constructor is not being called here?

Tags: c++

**For the following code, Fun() is returning a temporary object of Test type**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

using namespace std;
    
class Test
{
private:
    int x;
    static int count;
public:
    Test(int i=0 )  {cout<<"sumit";}
    Test(const Test& rhs) : x(rhs.x) { ++count; cout<<"sum"; }
    static int getCount() { return count; }
};
    
int Test::count = 0;
    
Test fun()
{
    Test ob(7);

    return ob;
}
    
int main()
{   
    Test a=fun();
    cout<<typeid(fun()).name();
    cout<< Test::getCount();
    return 0;
}
```

********Still copy is not taking place********

The output of the code:

constructor  4Test

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

Comment: There's Return Value Optimization.

Comment: Copy elision and return value optimization means there is no copying here.

Comment: You can get 1 or 0 copies, depending on whether your compiler decides to do NRVO on `return ob;`. Pre-C++17, you could get a second copy at `Test a=fun();` if compiler decided to not do RVO.